# Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk... is missing / not happening after flutter run. No app is saved on device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, build.gradle

When I flutter run, the app starts normally but when I stop the process, there is no app saved on the device as usual and also the employed build release is empty

normally when I `flutter run` I get this message:

```
- flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            25.1s⣽
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
```

this time, the line

```
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
```

is missing

im using visual studio code, anroid emulator, firebase:

```
    # Firebase
      firebase_core: ^1.12.0 
      cloud_firestore: ^2.5.4
      cloud_firestore_web: ^2.4.4
```

flutter doctor:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.1, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm, locale en-DE)
    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    [✓] VS Code (version 1.65.1)
    [✓] Connected device (2 available)
    [✓] HTTP Host Availability
    
    • No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do, flutter clean, also make sure the app is totally deleted from the device or emulator. if ur using emulator, clean it's data if ur using device, look for the app in settings an then app.

Comment: flutter clean does not work. The app-bundle that I uploaded in the play store also contains only an empty app, so I think the problem its not in the emulator

Answer (score 1):

If you are using emulator, make sure your emulator is identified by VS Code[something like this, in my case, iPhone 13 (ios Simulator)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvjY1.png)

If the device section has No Device printed, click on it to select an emulator, if you do not see the emulator name in the list, then try building a new emulator.

If you are using physical phone, turn on the USB debugging mode in settings section.

Comment: Thank you, but thats not the problem. The app runs smoothly on the emulator. Only after exiting the process, there is no app saved on the device and the produced app bundle does not contain an app that can be started

Answer (score -2):

restart your physical device and try again